# different hosnames for vm clones

Tags: 16.04, bash, scripts, virtualbox, hostname

Running virtualbox in ubuntu with lots of lubuntu clones but every clones has same hostname which puts me into trouble.Is there any way to assign different hostnames like `ubuntu-1,ubuntu-2` .. rather than manually edit /etc/hostname file. I think it can be done by simple bash script but i don't know how to do.

Comment: Did you think about [setting hostname with DHCP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104918/how-to-get-the-hostname-from-a-dhcp-server)?

Comment: i think it can only work  with bridged network adapter option under virtualbox,right?

Comment: i found this [link](https://gist.github.com/olegch/1671058)  but can't understand much of it.